# RailsTutorial: NoMethodError 'permanent' Rake::Test::CookieJar

Tags: railstutorial.org

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)      
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end
  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
   end
   def signed_in?
     !current_user.nil?
   end
   def current_user=(user)
     @current_user = user
  end
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

Tests defined in section `9.2.1 Requiring signed-in users` are failing:-
At first I was getting sign_in method not found then I added

```
include SessionsHelper
```

in spec/utilities.rb file after that I started getting below error, saying no method with name `permanent` exists in Rake::Test::CookieJar.

Is it due to some Gem version issue.

```
1) User Pages edit page 
 Failure/Error: before { sign_in user}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `permanent' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:0x007ff12c661e88>
 # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:3:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:55:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem and got it fixed.

It seems they are not referring to the `sign_in` method in `sessions_helper.rb` but the the `sign_in` method in `spec/support/utilities.rb`

In my case this helper method in `utilities.rb` had a different name, after renaming it everything worked fine :-)