# undefined method `permanent' when attempting to create a cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec

I've created a module so I can quickly create users, sign in as users, delete users and sign out users. Here is a simplified example:

```
module UserAuth
    def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = 'asda'
    end
end
```

However, if I run this spec:

```
describe 'UserAuth' do
    include UserAuth

    context 'signed up' do
        let(:user_1) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
        before { sign_up user_1 }

        contex 'signed in' do
            before { sign_in user_1 }

            it {}

        end
    end
end
```

I get this error:

```
   undefined method `permanent' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:#>
```

What I find weird about this is that `cookies` object is available, but this `permanent` method isn't for some reason. Can I resolve this issue by simply including another module in the UserAuth module? If so, what is the name of this module?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the RackTest CookieJar and Cookie classes do not offer these methods for testing within its MockSession. What I did is mock the methods setting cookies this way, and rather return my own result, or use RackTest's cookie methods to set cookies.

Note: In this example I'm mocking a method that is setting a cookie through a concern.

```
before :each do
  allow(MyConcern).to receive(cookie_method) { create(:cookie, :test) }
end

it 'tests cookie' do
  cookie_method

  expect {
    put item_path({test_id: 2})
  }.to change(Item, :test_id)

  expect(response.cookies[:cookie_id]).to eq 'test'
end
```

Here's another SO article going over this same issue, and [showing implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335183/using-cookies-with-racktest).

Another option is to use RackTest's CookieJar methods instead, which offer the basics of cookie creation, as well as few other options.

```
it 'has a cookie' do
  cookies[:remember_token] = 'my test'
  post items_path
  expect(response.cookies[:remember_token]).to eq 'my test'
end
```

You can check out the methods in the RackTest's [CookieJar/Cookie Source](https://github.com/rack-test/rack-test/blob/master/lib/rack/test/cookie_jar.rb) which is very straight-forward, but not so much for the [API docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/MockSession).

I hope that helps someone, and I also hope someone else comes along with a much better solution!

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you follow the method for testing this defined in the Rails Tutorial, as shown in http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code-sign_in_helper. The `CookieJar` object in `Rack::Test` is not the same as the one used by Rails in `ActionDispatch::Cookies`.

See related [RailsTutorial: NoMethodError 'permanent' Rake::Test::CookieJar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714242/railstutorial-nomethoderror-permanent-raketestcookiejar)