# Rspec stub doesn't work when called inside of a before block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a problem with rspec stubbing. I'm following this doc https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

```
describe Api::V1::ActionsController, type: :controller do
  let(:admin) { create :admin }

  subject { response }

  describe 'GET #index' do
    before :each do
      get :index
    end

    context 'admin' do
      before :each do
        allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return admin
        allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return true
      end

      it 'expects 200' do
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
  end
```

This test fails. And the interesting thing is that if I put these stubs to `spec_helper.rb` like

```
  config.before :each do
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return admin
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return true
  end
```

it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Where and how did you describe your `request`?

Comment: While not directly answering your question, you may be interested in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522294/rspec-how-to-stub-inherited-method-current-user-w-o-devise) about stubbing `current_user`. Answer still seems to work

Comment: @spickermann I updated my listing. it's controller spec

Comment: It'll be useful to also see the exception of that failed test, it'll be much easier to debug

Comment: @MaximFedotov In current_user method I have an api call to Auth0 service. So it fails because of WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError, but it's not important. It executes because current_user not stubbed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *guess* the problem is that this piece of code:

```
before :each do
  get :index
end
```

runs *before* the stubs:

```
before :each do
  allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return admin
  allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return true
end
```

`before` blocks are run from outside-in, and the block with the stubs is nested deeper. Therefore, by the time you stub the methods, `get :index` has already been executed.

Try this instead:

```
describe 'GET #index' do
  subject do   # define what `subject` will do, but don't actually run it just yet
    get :index
  end

  context 'admin' do
    before :each do
      allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return admin
      allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return true
    end

    it 'returns 200' do
      expect(subject).to be_success
      #      ^^^ now it's only here that the controller action is executed
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In my code, I have done exactly like you suggested but still don't work